# Magento 2 UiComponent form with tabs has empty fields

Tags: forms, tabs, field, magento2

I have and issue with empty form fields when I'm using tabs.
If I removing tabs usage, fields contains correct values.

My form uicomponent is large, so I will paste only important parts of configuration:

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_modulename_form.vendor_modulename_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item</item>
        ...
    </argument>
```

```
<settings>
        ...
        <namespace>vendor_modulename_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>vendor_modulename_form.vendor_modulename_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
        <layout>
            <navContainerName>left</navContainerName>
            <type>tabs</type>
        </layout>
    </settings>
```

```
<fieldset name="modules">
        <settings>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <opened>true</opened>
            <label translate="true">Details</label>
        </settings>
        <field name="name" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">module</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Name</label>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <dataScope>name</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
        ...
</fieldset>
```

Console log and magento logs are empty. I'm working in developer mode.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

In the dataprovider you have to wrap all the content of your fieldset with the key after loading the data.

Eg:

```
$id = $this->request->getParam('id');
        /** @var Collection $items */
        $items = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('id', $id)->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $formData['modules'] = $item->getData();
            $this->loadedData[$item->getId()] = $formData;
        }
```